# Implementing Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I am attempting to add a copy constructor to each in order to run the main function. What I have implemented right now currenrtly prints out "b2.valuea = -858993460 b2.valueb = 10" So it reads valueb correctly but obviously something is going wrong with valuea. Advice?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class A
{
  int valuea;

public:
int getValuea() const { return valuea; }
void setValuea(int x) { valuea = x; }

// copy constructor
A() {}
A(const A& original)
{
    valuea = original.valuea;
}


};

class B : public A
{

int valueb;

public:

int getValueb() const { return valueb; }
void setValueb(int x) { valueb = x; }

// copy constructor
B(){}
B(const B& original)
{
    valueb = original.valueb;
}

};

int main()
{

B b1;
b1.setValuea(5);
b1.setValueb(10);
B b2(b1);
cout << "b2.valuea = " << b2.getValuea() << "b2.valueb = " <<
    b2.getValueb() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the copy constructor of your base-class in your derived copy constructor.
Change it like:

```
B(const B& original) : A(original){
  valueb = original.valueb;
}
```

And it will output

```
b2.valuea = 5
b2.valueb = 10
```